# Tried to download windows 10 to my late 2012 mac mini but after restart it only shows me "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

Tags: display, bootcamp, mac-mini

I've been trying to download windows 10 onto my late 2012 mac mini through boot camp. After I went through all the steps to downloading through boot camp, it gave me a series of logins that I had to enter my system password in order to complete the installation and then it restarted. Now every time I restart my computer it leads me to a screen that says "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" and I don't know how to fix that.
My main monitor also isn't connecting to the computer for some reason?? I've already disconnected it and reconnected it but to no avail, I'm looking at this black screen through my huion display tablet, which is connected through the thunderbolt outlet of this computer.

**How do I fix my computer?**

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant does not download Windows 10. The Boot Camp Assistant does download the Windows Support Software from Apple. Are you sure you installed Windows 10? Did you reach a point where you were asked for a product key?

Comment: You can try boot your Mac holding alt key. Normally you will have the choice Mac Os x.

Comment: Try booting to internet recovery - cmd-R - you can launch diskutil to see whether there's still a viable OSX partition left .. and you may need to reformat the disk / repartition / combinatoin of the two to get it back to one of the partition formats that OSX will be happy with.